# How can I run import statement containing typscript's transcompiled js file in browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and just started learning - I want to execute this very simple code in browser- how can I run this ?--

Person.ts

```
export class Person {
 age(): number {
  return 100;
 }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Person } from "./Person";

const person = new Person();

window.alert(person.age());
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="Person.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

  <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  </body>

 </html>
```

main.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Person_1 = require("./Person");
var person = new Person_1.Person();
window.alert(person.age());
```

Person.js  (Sorry here is the edited code)

```
   "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person() {
    }
    Person.prototype.age = function () {
        return 100;
    };
    return Person;
    }());
    exports.Person = Person;
```

Comment: Your `Person.js` file contains the same TypeScript code from `Person.ts`? How is that possible? The contents of `Person.js` is invalid JavaScript code.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong file there. Now I have pasted the correct file. Plz now check this.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? I see you are loading person.js before main.js. This should be enougth for code to work.

I may also suggest to configure you transpiler to produce single main.js from all you ts files. In most cases this is preferred solution.

You may use create-react-app as reference for webpack configuration for transpiling multiple ts to single js.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console of your browser's Development Tools window?

Comment: @BartHofland yes -- "exports is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined", you may need to either install and use CommonJS, or you should set the module code generation setting of the TypeScript compiler to "es6".

Furthermore, if you include `Person.js` in your HTML file, you should probably include it as a module too (like you did with `Main.js`). But actually, you can leave the inclusion of `Person.js` away in your HTML file, since it is only used by `Main.js`.